# Concat text variables in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have this code and I want to concatenate the variables but don't work.
This is my DDL code for the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function acd.add_credito2()
RETURNS void
SET SCHEMA 'acd'
SET search_path = acd
AS $$
DECLARE
    auxsigla text;
    auxnome text;
    _sql text := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW acd.teste AS SELECT md.matriz_disciplina_id AS id, dcp.nome, mc.curso, mc.versao AS matriz';    
    _join text := ' FROM matriz_disciplina as md LEFT JOIN disciplina as dcp ON md.disciplina_id = dcp.disciplina_id LEFT JOIN matriz_curricular as mc ON md.matriz_curricular_id = mc.matriz_curricular_id';

BEGIN
    select into auxsigla, auxnome from ( select sigla, nome from acd.categoria_credito where categoria_credito_id = 9) as foo;
    _join := _join || ' LEFT JOIN (SELECT creditos, matriz_disciplina_id FROM acd.disciplina_credito WHERE categoria_credito_id = ' || x || ') AS ' || "auxsigla" ' ON ' || "auxsigla" || '.matriz_disciplina_id = md.matriz_disciplina_id';
        _sql := _sql || ', ' || "auxsigla" || '.' || auxnome || ' AS ' || auxnome;

    _sql := _sql || _join;

    EXECUTE _sql;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

So, when I execute the function

```
database-1=# select acd.add_credito2();
```

This error appears:

```
ERROR:  type "auxsigla" does not exist
LINE 1: ...WHERE categoria_credito_id = ' || x || ') AS ' || "auxsigla"...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  SELECT _join || ' LEFT JOIN (SELECT creditos, matriz_disciplina_id FROM acd.disciplina_credito WHERE categoria_credito_id = ' || x || ') AS ' || "auxsigla" ' ON ' || "auxsigla" || '.matriz_disciplina_id = md.matriz_disciplina_id'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function add_credito2() line 13 at assignment
```

Can anyone help me? I don't know what to do now.

(I know, this study view don't have a purpose but this is the idea that I want to use in the real view)

Comment: You should really use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) with `%I` for table and column names and `%L` for parameters to generate dynamic SQL - that will make your life a lot easier (and the code easier to read and maintain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from this construct:

```
"auxsigla" ' ON '
```

You forgot a concatenation operator `||` between these two tokens, and now the SQL parser interprets it as

```
data_type string_constant
```

which is a way to specify constants of a certain data type.

Working examples would be `DATE '2018-09-20'` or `INTEGER '-20'`.

Your function has numerous other problems, two of which I could spot:

- `select into auxsigla, auxnome from` will always set the variables to `NULL` because you forgot to specify which columns you want to select.
- you do not properly escape single quotes while composing your dynamic query string. What if `auxsigla` has the value `with'quote`?

  Use `format()` or `quote_literal()` and `quote_ident()` for that.

Comment: Yeah.. I realized that missing operator, thanks (and the missing columns either)